# Timestamp (date/time) system used by LibreOffice Calc / OpenOffice Calc spreadsheet applications?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, openoffice, openoffice-calc, timestamp

What system does LibreOffice Calc / OpenOffice Calc use to represent timestamps (dates/times) as numbers?

It's apparent that they don't use the standard integer [**epoch times**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) that are common in computer programming languages and many operating systems such as Linux and Unix.

The easiest way to view such values is to enter `=NOW()` into a spreadsheet cell, and format it as a *"general"* number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What system does LibreOffice Calc use to represent timestamps as numbers?

> **General information about Calc's Date and Time functions**
>
> **Calc uses 1899-12-30 as the default start date (day 0)** but you can go to Tools ▸ Options ▸ LibreOffice Calc ▸ Calculate to select
> alternative start dates; however, unless you have specific
> requirements for compatibility with legacy spreadsheet applications,
> we recommend that you do not change this setting. If you copy and
> paste cells containing date values between different spreadsheets,
> check that both documents are set to use the same start date to avoid
> unexpected changes to the dates displayed.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

> Negative date-time serial numbers correspond to dates earlier than
> Calc's start date. Calc calculates all dates back to 15th October 1582
> using the Gregorian calendar. The day before this is 4th October 1582,
> and Calc uses the Julian calendar for earlier dates.

Source: [Documentation/Calc Functions/DATE - The Document Foundation Wiki](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Calc_Functions/DATE)

---

#### So why 1899-12-30?

Probably for historical reasons <sup>(pun intended)</sup> because of a bug in Lotus 1-2-3.

> Actually, this number is one greater than the actual number of days. This is because Excel behaves as if the date 1900-Feb-29 existed. It did not. The year 1900 was not a leap year (the year 2000 is a leap year). In Excel, the day after 1900-Feb-28 is 1900-Feb-29. In reality, the day after 1900-Feb-28 was 1900-Mar-1 . This is not a "bug". Indeed, it is by design. Excel works this way because it was truly a bug in Lotus 123. When Excel was introduced, 123 has nearly the entire market for spreadsheet software. **Microsoft decided to continue Lotus' bug, in order to fully compatible. Users who switched from 123 to Excel would not have to make any changes to their data.** As long as all your dates later than 1900-Mar-1, this should be of no concern.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source: [Why is 1899-12-30 the zero date in Access / SQL Server instead of 12/31?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3963650/3536342) answer by [wkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297696/wkl).

See also [My First BillG Review – Joel on Software](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/06/16/my-first-billg-review/) and [Set the Flux Capacitor for 12/30/1899 - The Daily WTF](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/set-the-flux-capacitor-for-12-30-1899)

Looks like this 'tradition' was carried over from Excel to LibreOffice Calc.

---

#### How can I convert LibreOffice dates to standard integer epoch times?

If you want to convert LibreOffice dates to standard epoch dates (seconds since 1970) then see [How to convert formatted date to unix epoch in Libreoffice calc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59708769/3536342) answer by [SentientFlesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11019416/sentientflesh)

Comment: Thanks David.  Answer upvoted and accepted.  Any idea why they chose 1899-12-30 instead of the standard beginning of epoch time (1970-01-01)?

Comment: I think it is important to note that programming and operating system epoch times are commonly presented as *integers* representing the number of *seconds* since the beginning of the epoch, whereas LibreOffice and OpenOffice use a system that uses *rational numbers* (mathematics terminology) to represent the number of fractional *days* since the beginning of their epoch.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Answer updated

Comment: Thanks for the update.  As an aside, I read all the relevant LibreOffice help before composing and posting my question (by now, I think I've literally read *all* of the LibreOffice Calc help pages!).  Thus, I was surprised to learn that some relevant info is present in the the online LibreOffice *documentation*.  Apparently, the LibreOffice *help pages* and the LibreOffice *documentation* contain completely different information.  Ugh!